# Analyzing map data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, cartography, tiger

I downloaded vector data of a map from tiger products and loaded them in QGIS. it renders the map as expected and I can see the attributes too. but how to understand the data and the map ? I mean the link between the map lines and attributes.

the attributes table for a line in map is as follows: 
OBJECTID LINEARID FULLNAME MTFCC if I select a line and view its WKT it is giving its latitude and longitude coordinates which are exactly matching with google mpas.

The problem that teasing me is how this map and the data is related ? Is the attribute table data is the vector data of this map, if not whats the exact vector data. can some one provide any example vector for a map line.

Comment: Where did you download the data from? There should be an explanation about the attributes on the source.

Comment: Tiger Products  website

Comment: geometry is stored in the file, not attribute table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to find out what the attributes of any dataset represent and classify is to lookup the [MetaData](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata), In your case you should consult the metadata files the the US Census Bureau maintains of the TIGER dataset.

Read [this](https://ask.census.gov/faq.php?id=5000&faqId=7823), the metadata files (.xml with the downloaded shapefiles) define exactly what is present in the data

> *...This includes MAF/TIGER Feature Class Codes (MTFCCs) and legal and statistical area description codes (LSADs).  The MTFCC codes classify and define each feature.  For example, a user could determine if a place is incorporated (legal) or a census designated place (statistical) from the MTFCC value....*

As far as vector data is concerned, I think you are confusing what vector data is, it is the representation of the world using points, lines, and polygons.

Take a look at [this](https://www.gislounge.com/geodatabases-explored-vector-and-raster-data/) to get a general idea about Vector and Raster Data.

The multiple files you see with the `.shp` file all come together to make the shapefile each of them containing different components, for example, the `.shp` file contains the geometry of the features, the `.dbf` file stores the attribute information (the MTFCC codes, the object name and so on) and the `.prj` file contains information about the projection system, for  a complete list of extensions and what they contain, take a look at [this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Shapefile_file_extensions).

Comment: the above links are very informative. Thanks for sharing them. still one point is not clear to me. I have .dbf, .shp, .shx files all the files when I add  them as vector layer  independently  to the QGIS they are showing the information accurately. how come this three files showing same info ? are they different formats of same file or do each file has it sown importance ? I tried opening them in notepad but its encrypted. Still I dint get the file with coordinates information and How can I view them in QGIS or to store in DB for further processing. could you throw some light on these things

Comment: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Shapefile_file_extensions explains what all the different files with the .shp file are, collectively all these files make up the shapefile.

Comment: if you want to import your shapefiles to a database, and assuming you want to import the geometry as well as the attributes, you need a spatial database like postgis.

Comment: Np, happy to help.